# Replace browser spinner with custom spinner

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

When we click on any link, we see a browser spinner till the content we clicked gets loaded. I want to *replace* the browser spinner with any other **custom spinner** during that loading time.

[image]

Is it possible ? If yes, how ? Can anyone please, help me with this ?

Comment: Your page cannot manipulate the browser itself.

Comment: Nice idea. You could try an animated favicon I guess. https://www.google.nl/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=animated+favicon&spell=1

Comment: @HaukurHaf if we can't replace but then can't we just don't show the spinner ?

Comment: Nope.  Why would you want to do that anyway?  Its a vital indicator to tell the user that the browser is doing something.

Comment: Yes, my client was seeking that. They think that browser spinner is  unnoticeable so their requirement is to hide the browser spinner and show custom spinner in page itself.

Comment: Just show a custom spinner on the page and leave the browser spinner alone :-)